# Edit Extent of a Shapefile ArcMap10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, extents

I created a polyline feature and then I created a shapefile. Then overlayed another map and I wanted to analyse the distribution of the distance from the polyline, but the extents of the shapefile of the polyline are limited by the polyline lengths, cutting out part of the area I would be interested to (as you can see in the pic below).
Is it possible to edit the size of the shapefile, so I can cover all the area?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not too sure what it is you're wanting to do ... You mean you want the shapefile to physically be larger to encompass the polyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are computing distance (I'm guessing using a buffer tool given the concentric color zones), under Environments, expand Processing Extent and set the Extent to your Polygon file.

[image]

[image]